# PHP not renaming uploaded file

Tags: php

I am uploading an image and then trying to rename the image like this:

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["eventimage"]["name"]);
$uploadOk=1;


  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["eventimage"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {

  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["eventimage"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

} else {

  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

}

//Now rename
$new_name_here = 'file_' . rand(0, 10000) . '.' . end(explode(".", $_FILES["eventimage"]["name"]));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["eventimage"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/" . $new_name_here);
```

Problem is that the image is now being renamed.

I'm I doing this in the wrong place.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two calls to [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) in your code but you can only use it *once* per uploaded file.

Once you've used `move_uploaded_file()` to make the temporary / uploaded file "permenant", you'll want to start using [`rename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) instead.

I would, however, suggest to not use the original file's name at all when moving it via `move_uploaded_file()` since malicious users could easily fake something nasty in there. Instead, try using the randomness you're using for the second move to replace the first:

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . 'file_' . rand(0, 10000) . '.' . end(explode(".", $_FILES["eventimage"]["name"]));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["eventimage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
  echo "The file ". htmlentities(basename( $_FILES["eventimage"]["name"])) . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Side-note: I have also thrown in a call to [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when outputting the user-supplied file name; without it, you're open to a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabily.